# How to negate records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to figure out how many parts a person bought in a certain month.  Each record comes from an invoice with part orders.

The important parts of the table are:

```
Orders (PartNo, Quantity, Price, discount, EXP_Price, date)
```

the data would looks like this:

```
P1  1 30.00 15.00 15.00 11-NOV-06
P2  1 30.00 6.00  24.00 19-NOV-06
P2 -2 30.00 0.00 -30.00 11-NOV-06
P2  2 30.00 0.00  30.00 20-NOV-06
```

The issue I'm having is with the last two lines.  The last two orders cancel each other out, as if someone rang the last part in error and had to cancel it out of the final bill.

How does someone construct a query that account for the fact that the last two rows negate each other?

Thanks in advance

OK I've been trying this and iteraction around it

```
select PartNo
from Practice
Where PARTNO = (

  select PARTNO , SUM(Quantity) 
  from Practice
  group by PARTNO);
```

The questions just states how many parts did Joe Smith (the name that corresponds to this invoice) buy in the month of November(sorry not mouth) of November.  Know this guy he will want us to account for the fact that Joe never actually bought those parts since they were never charged to the buyer.

Comment: Personally, I never buy parts in a mouth... I think we need to see what you have tried already. Also, does the assignment specify the net of parts bought? If it's just parts bought, not net parts returned, then P2 did buy 2 parts. If it's net, she would have 0 parts. If net, you can just use a SUM and GROUP BY, if not net, you need to use a CASE inside the SUM to handle the negative amounts. What happens if the parts are returned in a different month? Would you expect to see negative parts bought?

Comment: Do you want to show only the rows that negate each other or show only the ones that do not have a corresponding "VOID" or negation?

Comment: Also, the data does not look right. How can some one "void" or negate a transaction before it even happened. On 11-Nov-06 the transaction was negated but the actual corresponding transaction happened on 20-Nov-06. Is that even a valid scenario? If so how?

Comment: Sorry I put the month data in for illustrative purposes.  The dates are really attached to an invoice.

Comment: Annjawn yes show the rows that are left after the negation.

Comment: @user3786519 Try this- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/adc27/2

Comment: From what I understand of the requirements so far, you are almost there, but may be over thinking it. it looks like if you just use the "select sum(quantity) from practice" you should get your answer for the total parts, but I feel like there should be more data, like a filter on the month somewhere, and multiple invoices.

Comment: There would have to be a sub query that picks all the records that correspond with novemeber.  If we just assume that all the records are in November then he will say what if you had a billion rows.  I was intially stuck on the first part.  The query I posted tell me there are too many values.  I'm assuming I need to split this into two sub tables somehow.I guess the last part would be to use count function to add the rows to give me total parts purchased

Comment: Annjawn thanks but extract was not one of the functions he taught us so we will not be permitted to use it.

Comment: Okay, you can use `to_char(date_time,'MM')` instead, but you get the idea.

Comment: If that's the case, then you just need to add a WHERE to what I wrote above and filter by date range. Do you know TO_DATE or BETWEEN? No need for a sub query.

Comment: He did not teach us TO-DATE or between, but this guy is such a jerk I'll use between if it gets me the answer and minus a couple of points so be it.

Comment: select sum(quantity)
from orders
where date_time >= '01-NOV-06'
and date_time < '01-DEC-06';

Comment: Thanks everyone, how do you use between just for my etification?

Comment: select sum(quantity)
from orders
where trunc(date_time) between '01-NOV-06' and '30-NOV-06'; I added trunc to make this work in case there are time values included with the date.

Comment: Bob for some reason when I try you last bit of code it's only returning the first row? Nevermind I created a new table to practice and had not inserted all the rows yet.

Comment: There is only one row. How many parts did he order? He ordered two parts. If the question was how many of each part did he order, it would have one row for each part.

Comment: Just one more thing... i would be worried about the -2 on Parts... the question doesn't ask how many parts did he keeps. If you want to exclude the returns, just add "and quantity > 0" to your query.

Comment: I thought of that but that would return too many values i.e the last row.  The end would result in too many parts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very simple, you just need to sum all columns multiplied to the sign of quantity.

```
select PartNo, sum(Quantity) as Quantity, sum(Price*sign(Quantity)) as Price, sum(discount*sign(Quantity)) as discount, sum(EXP_Price*sign(Quantity)) as EXP_Price
from Orders 
group by PartNo
```